# Downloading a file from the website via the download link

Tags: c#

There's a code that downloads files by links (.exe), which actually needs a link to download the file, it can be a direct link or a link to the file that needs to be downloaded. In 80% of cases, everything works (https://ru.download.nvidia.com/GFE/GFEClient/3.25.1.27/GeForce_Experience_v3.25.1.27.exe (https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/geforce/geforce-experience/)), but where you need to confirm the cookie (https://drivers.amd.com/drivers/installer/22.20/beta/amd-software-adrenalin-edition-22.8.2-minimalsetup-220825_web.exe (https://www.amd.com/en/support)), the download doesn't work

Maybe it can somehow work normally?

```
using var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
handler.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
handler.UseCookies = true;
using var client = new HttpClient(handler);

SaveFile(client, fileUri, destinationFolder)

async Task SaveFile(HttpClient client, Uri uri, string destinationFolder)
{
    using var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
    using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
    var name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".exe";
    using var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(destinationFolder, name), FileMode.CreateNew);
    await stream.CopyToAsync(fs);
}
```

Comment: Somehow your question is missing an actual question. If the site blocks downloads directly by going to the URL you need to figure out what is needed (Cookies, HTTP Referer, etc) and try to fake it. But that will always be brittle